# Swift refactor nested function with API request

Tags: ios, swift, api, callback

I'm working on API calls in Swift and have some questions about it.
I've experienced JavaScript API calls before and I wanted to add async/ await stuff to my Swift project. But since I'm using Swift 5, I cannot use async / await yet (I heard I can use it from Swift 5.5).

I'm writing a function for API calls and reload the collection view in my project as below code.

```
var events = [Event]()

func populateCV() {
    var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Event>()

    // What I want to do here
    1. fetchEvents() // call "fetchEvents" function and get events with API request and update the events array above.
    2. snapshot.appendItems(events) // append items (events array) to snapshot variable
    3. collectionViewDataSource?.apply(snapshot) // reflect the changes with the new snapshot
    
}


func fetchEvents() {
    // in this function I used Alamofire and I've got the data back (which is "result" below), and I update the events array with results array.
    events = results
}
```

Basically, what I want to do here is update the events array by API request result, and then add updated events to the snapshot to update the collectionview.

Since the API request takes some time, I want to wait for the call of `snapshot.appendItems(events)` and `collectionViewDataSource?.apply(snapshot)` until the events array is fully updated by the API call.

So, I add completion to fetchEvents and write something like below.

```
var events = [Event]()

func populateCV() {
    var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Event>()

    fetchEvents {
        snapshot.appendItems(self.events)
        self.collectionViewDataSource?.apply(snapshot)
    }
    
}


func fetchEvents(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    // in this function I used Alamofire and I've got the data back (which is "result" below), and I update the events array with results array.
    events = results
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        completion()
    }
}
```

It's working now, but I was wondering if I have to work on several completions, my code will become messy.

For example, fetch data and use the data in nested function, and then use the data which got from the previous function ... and so on.
I guess in that case, my function becomes something like

```
 fetchEvents {
     doTask1 {
        doTask2 {
            // and more...
        }
     }
 }
```

So if I want to avoid those callback hells, how can I write the completion in Swift?
Also, I add completion in my second fetchEvents function but is there more cleaner code to update the collection view with newly returned data from API call?

Comment: Might be a good idea to look into Combine and its Future publisher.

Answer (score 0):

Yea this is one of the draw backs of using the completion paradigm in Swift. async/await will be awesome to use, not doubt.
I'm not aware of a way around it if you insists using the completion paradigm.

You can how ever change your code and use Reactiv (using RxSwift or Combine) paradigm, while wrap your completion with Observables.

For example:

```
fetchEvents(escaping completion: (Result<[Event]>) -> ()) {
... Alamofire and parsing code
}
```

Will be re-written with RxSwift as

```
fetchEvents() -> Observalbe<[Event]> {
  return Observable.create { [weak self] observer -> Disposable in
    fetchEvents { events in
      observer.onNext(events)
      observer.onCompleted()
  }
  return Disposables.create()
}
```

}

And so for the other functions `doTask1` and `doTask1`.

When you will come to chain them it will look something like

```
fetchEvents()
  .map/flatMap/do { return doTask1 ... (rx operator if you want to map the events}
  .map/flatMap/do { return  doTask2 ... (rx operator if you want to map the events}
```

An other alternative is to use Promises like in Javascript

Take a look at `https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit` it is a great framework.

If PromiseKit seems like an overhead in your case, you can take inspiration from [this](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/under-the-hood-of-futures-and-promises-in-swift/) great article by John Sundell on how to create your own Promise/Future and chain them